Optimal map printing algorithm
I do the occasional long distance hike and often require printing 10+ A3 maps.
I'm trying to find an algorithmic solution to the manual process of printing off multiple maps of a route.
The manual process is often non-optimal, in which I mean pages should be kept to a minimum. Eg. Extra pages are added, where as if I had moved previous pages over slightly here and there it would have encompassed the route in fewer pages.
To complicate things printing can be done in both portrait and landscape modes.
Id really appreciate a push in the right direction. Is there a simple solution or does it require some more elaborate thinking?
To clarify: Given a list of 2d points, find the minimum amount of boxes they will fit in. With the boxes being either wh (portrait) or hw (landscape). Also the maps cannot be rescaled.

"To clarify: Given a list of 2d points, find the minimum amount of boxes they will fit in." For every such list, the answer is one (1) box.

With the boxes being either wh (portrait) or hw (landscape)

This is a clustering problem.  You want to find the minimal number of clusters that do not exceed a maximum extent ( the page size ) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

@User34 Are you still interested?  You need to get this question re-opened.  Edit it to specify that your maps cannot be rescaled ( obvious, I know, but sadly questions get closed by people who do not understand them ) and request it be re-opened.

@500-InternalServerError: Now that "Also the maps cannot be rescaled." has been added, the problem is well defined and interesting -- please vote to reopen!

@RobbyCornelissen: Now that "Also the maps cannot be rescaled." has been added, the problem is well defined and interesting -- please vote to reopen!

I assume "landscape or portrait" implies no rotation?

@Neil  Obviously the map cannot be rotated because you always want North to be pointing to the "top" of the page.  The pages can be rotated be 90 degrees for landscape or portrait, as the questions states.

A modified K-means clustering algorithm solves this problem almost optimally.

Loop until all route coordinates are covered by a clusters page

Add a new cluster. Starting position is selected as a random coordinate not currently covered by any clusters page
Iterate x times

Assign route coordinates to the nearest clusters centroid
Calculate centroid as the middle of its range (midrange) of assigned coordinates
Choose orientation that fits the most uncovered coordinates





Source: https://github.com/DM-UK/PageFit
Using the midrange for calculating the centroids position, instead of a mean average led to fitting in fewer pages.
I can only describe this behavior as: clusters using the mean would get 'stuck', where as using midrange would 'spread' into space along the whole path.


A two-pass algorithm solves this problem.  First pass maximizes point coverage with no page overlaps.  Second pass clusters uncovered points, with page overlaps allowed.
  ( Pass 1 )
- Create a page that covers the first waypoint and the maximum number of other waypoints
- FOR ever
   - find page margin ( top, left, right, bottom ) nearest to last waypoint covered
   - add page adjacent without overlap to margin that covers the maximum number of new waypoints
   - IF last waypoint covered
        - BREAK
- ENDLOOP for ever

  ( Pass 2 )
- FOR pageCount = 1 to 100
  - Apply K-Means algo to uncovered waypoints to find pageCount clusters
  - Create page centred on center of each cluster
  - If all waypoints on at least one page
      - DONE
- ENDLOOP over pageCount
- FAILED

I have implemented this algorithm in C++ ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/Mapify )
For the sample waypoint data provided, here is the result.

40 pages of 6925 by 10000
Page 1 center 408823, 390971
Page 2 center 408130, 400971
Page 3 center 406053, 410971
Page 4 center 399128, 413971
Page 5 center 398435, 423971
Page 6 center 397743, 433971
Page 7 center 395665, 443971
Page 8 center 388740, 448971
Page 9 center 395665, 451971
Page 10 center 388740, 456971
Page 11 center 388048, 466971
Page 12 center 381123, 471971
Page 13 center 383200, 481971
Page 14 center 386663, 491971
Page 15 center 387355, 501971
Page 16 center 390818, 511971
Page 17 center 397743, 512971
Page 18 center 394280, 522971
Page 19 center 387355, 527971
Page 20 center 380430, 530971
Page 21 center 373505, 529971
Page 22 center 366580, 530971
Page 23 center 370043, 540971
Page 24 center 369350, 550971
Page 25 center 367273, 560971
Page 26 center 369350, 570971
Page 27 center 376275, 569971
Page 28 center 383200, 574971
Page 29 center 385278, 584971
Page 30 center 381815, 594971
Page 31 center 379738, 604971
Page 32 center 381815, 614971
Page 33 center 388740, 619971
Page 34 center 385278, 629971
Page 35 center 386387, 472062
Page 36 center 385439, 472153
Page 37 center 393812, 517965
Page 38 center 369847, 525381
Page 39 center 371060, 535894
Page 40 center 374064, 541344

You cand download the Mapify application from https://github.com/JamesBremner/Mapify/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Thank you very much for your reply. I've implemented  K-means clustering and find the solution unsatisfactory. It gives a fair approximation but the 'pages' seem to overlap too much, even before every point is covered. I've uploaded a screenshot to make things clearer: https://ibb.co/hYJSgMp

Apologies for being vague, I have not quantified 'overlap' any more than by sight. As can be seen in the screenshot, the pages are bunched up in places (as would be expected with K means clustering?). Please note: for illustration purposes the screenshot uses a K value less than required to cover all the points (bunching much more when all points covered) and for debug purposes only uses portrait orientation. I should have uploaded a screenshot with all points covered which I think was K value +10 which would have emphasized how much overlapping occurs.

Im afraid I only have it as a .gpx file: https://www.peakdistrict.gov.uk/__data/assets/file/0020/68006/TPTTrans-Pennine-Trail.gpx. I don't believe it's a problem with the implementation but with the nature of K-means clustering and the calculation of centroids? I'm wondering if some post processing needs to be done or an alternative approach altogether?

Please provide your input data ( i.e. the waypoints ).  The link in your last comment is broken ( "403 forbidden" ).

(double) x, y values: https://pastebin.com/raw/YdCucmg2

Thank you.  I have added your test data to the github repo. https://github.com/JamesBremner/Mapify/blob/main/dat/test2.txt

What is the map scale you want to use, and what is the paper size you want?

A3 paper size minus 20mm margins (0.277M x 0.400M)  @ 25000 scale

Sorry, I do not know what "25000 scale" means.  Your waypoints ate lat and lon, so I need to know what lat and lon one page of your paper would cover.

It is probably better that we discuss these details in github.  If you let me know your github handle, I can add you to the repo.  ( If you don't have one, then you can create one for free )

Sorry, the waypoints have already been converted to cartesian coordinates. So one page would cover 6925 x 10000.

https://github.com/JamesBremner/Mapify/issues/1

Thank you for your help. I would have never learnt about cluster algorithms otherwise. If you'd like to see my progress: https://github.com/DM-UK/MapMate

There is no code in your code repository!!!  Looks like you are using the same test waypoints that you gave me.  Why is the waypoint file not in your repo?  How many pages do you need to cover all the waypoints?  ( The latest Mapify needs 40, see my answer )

I would like to see your progress.  However, the repository you link to in your last comment does not exist!!!
